# Sencha Touch: List does not fire itemtap

Tags: list, extjs, touch

I am building a small demo application using Sencha touch: 
I have run into an issue with the list display followed by the itemtap even firing.I had this working in a previous application but cannot find out why its not firing in the current application
I have added itemtap methods as listeners, on the view, in the controller, but none of them fire. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Thanks In Advance for your help.
PS

Main.js

```
Ext.define('KapselApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'mainview',
    requires: [
        'KapselApp.view.ExpApproval',
        'KapselApp.view.ExpApproval.Details',
        'KapselApp.view.ExpApproval.Confirm'
    ],
    config: {
        autoDestroy: false,

        navigationBar: {
            ui: 'sencha',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'editButton',
                    text: 'Edit',
                    align: 'right',
                    hidden: true,
                    hideAnimation: Ext.os.is.Android ? false : {
                        type: 'fadeOut',
                        duration: 200
                    },
                    showAnimation: Ext.os.is.Android ? false : {
                        type: 'fadeIn',
                        duration: 200
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    id: 'saveButton',
                    text: 'Save',
                    ui: 'sencha',
                    align: 'right',
                    hidden: true,
                    hideAnimation: Ext.os.is.Android ? false : {
                        type: 'fadeOut',
                        duration: 200
                    },
                    showAnimation: Ext.os.is.Android ? false : {
                        type: 'fadeIn',
                        duration: 200
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        items: [
            { xtype: 'expApprovals' }
        ]
    }

});
```

ExpApproval.view

```
Ext.define('KapselApp.view.ExpApproval', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'expApprovals',
    config: {
        title: 'Expense Approval',
        cls: 'x-ExpApprovals',
        items: [{
                xtype: 'list',
                //id: 'expApproval',
                store: expApprovals,
                itemTpl: ['<div class="headshot" style="background-image:url(ExpType.Images/blue_btn_left.png);"></div>',
                        'From:{UserName} {WorkItem}',
                        '<div>Subject:{SUBJECT}</div>'
                ],
                listeners: {
                    itemtap: function(view, index, item, e){
                        alert ('itemtap 1');
                    }
                }
        }],
        itemtap: function(me, index, target, record){
                   alert ('itemtap');
                    //do other logic here

        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        console.log ('KapselApp.view.ExpApproval:initialize: ');

    }
});
```

Controller

```
Ext.define('KapselApp.controller.ExpApprovalApplication', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            main: 'mainview',
            editButton: '#editButton',
            expApprovalDetails: 'expapproval-details',
            expApprovalList: 'expApprovals',
            confirmExpApprovals: 'expapproval-confirm',
            contacts: 'contacts',
            showContact: 'contact-show',
            editContact: 'contact-edit',
            saveButton: '#saveButton'
        },
        control: {
            main: {
                push: 'onMainPush',
                pop: 'onMainPop'
            },
            editButton: {
                tap: 'onContactEdit'
            },
            expApprovalList: {
                itemtap: 'onExpApprovalsSelect'
            },
            saveButton: {
                tap: 'onContactSave'
            },
            editContact: {
                change: 'onContactChange'
            },
            'expApproval list' : {itemtap: 'onExpApprovalsSelect'},
        }
    },
onExpApprovalsSelect: function(list, index, node, record) {
        alert ('onExpApprovalsSelect');
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Ok .. found the sollution to your problem. You made the same mistake as I did. you overrode the initialize method in the list view without calling in the initiallize method "this.callParent()". By adding this in my code events started firing. I am sure it will work in yours.

So your List initialize handler should look something like this:

```
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('eventsView being initialized.');
        this.callParent();
    },
```

You can still use the code bellow to check which events are being fired for debugging in similar situations.

---- Previous post ----
I am facing a similar issue. I am extending Ext.dataview.List and have a controller capture the itemtap event but the event does not seem to be firing.

I tried adding the following code to capture all the events being fired... The list seems to fire the show event and the scroll events but no other such as itemtap, etc ...

```
Ext.define('Override.mixin.Observable', {
override : 'Ext.mixin.Observable',

fireEvent : function(eventName, args) {
    console.log('Event:', eventName, args);
    this.callOverridden(arguments);
    //debugger;
},

fireAction : function(eventName) {
    console.log('Action:',eventName);

    this.callOverridden(arguments);
}
});
```

Try adding this code and see if you are getting the itemtap events.

Let me know if you make any progress.

Comment: From the tests I have been conductin strangely enough  I am able to catch the show event but no itemtap event seems to be firing. With the code above I can see scroll events happening when I scroll the list contents up and down but when I click on the any item nothing happens, no events are registered in the console, no item is selected, absolutely nothing.

Comment: Ok .. found the sollution to your problem. You made the same mistake as I did. you overrode the initialize method in the list view without calling in the initiallize method **"this.callParent()"**. By adding this in my code events started firing. I am sure it will work in yours.

Comment: Please do not forget to accept the answer .. I really need the reputation since I am new to Stackoverflow.

Comment: This is the right answer - I wish I could accept it for the OP.